# AWS EC2 instances launched from common, custom AMI

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, windows-server-2016

I've created several Windows Server 2016 instances from an AMI that I created with custom baseline settings. So far everything is working fine but I've noticed that the first instance that I set up using the AMI has the full instance description in the top right(Example below).

```
Hostname: EC2AMAZ-4R59V4S
Instance ID: i-4l6khw5l7we435j
Private IP Address: 10.0.1.112
Instance Size: m4.xlarge
Availability Zone: us-west-1
Architecture: AMD64
Total Memory: 16 GB
Network Performance: High
```

Each subsequent instance has only a 2 line description(hostname and architecture) and the hostname is the same as all the others.  It hasn't caused any other issues that I have noticed yet because AWS uses a different, private hostname(ie, `ip-10.0.1.112.ec2.internal`).  Is there a way to correct this issue and are there any other issues that this may cause going forward?

Answer (score 1):

You will want to Sysprep the instances before you take the snapshot to create your custom AMI. Assuming you're using the Windows AMIs that Amazon provides that has built in SPLA licensing (the OS licensing is blended into the EC2 instance rate), you can use EC2Config Service included in the image. Launch it from the start menu immediately before you are ready to take the snapshot and choose Shutdown with Sysprep.

More details are in the AWS EC2 docs here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ami-create-standard.html.